# Razor Engine GetReferences() throws path error when called from Azure Function

Tags: azure, razor, azure-devops, razorengine

I know this is a duplicate of this post:
[Nicely asked question :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52017632/razor-engine-library-throws-error-on-azure-function) 
But since my reputation is not high enough here on SO I can`t add a comment to ask what happened, or how the poster of the question resolved the issue, so I am asking here, since "googling" did not provide any answers. So basically, what could be the cause of this issue? Does anybody know how to resolve it? 
Thanks..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please don't rely on the link to another question to explain your scenario. How can the problem be reproduced? What exactly did you try to resolve the issue and what was the result? I encourage you to edit your question and provide all relevant details so that others may be able to help you.

Comment: @Uzair A. Hi, thanks :) It is basically the same thing, once I call RazorEngine.Razor.Compile(templateName, templateModel); from my code I get the same error as in the link. Using a debugger I found that the error comes from GetReferences() method as in the link provided. When I inspect (new UseCurrentAssembliesReferenceResplver()).GetReferences(context, includedAssemblies); i can inspect ResultsView and there it says "The given path's format is not supported". I can't see witch path, that is the main issue i guess..